# Helper functions of SCSS and Compass in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 / Web Essentials?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials, compass

I recently migrated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and installed Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4. I downloaded the compass files and tried to do my very first sass (scss) files.

Two issues I could solve already by myself (see "solved" below), still two more to go :-(

**OPEN: Detailed error message?**

I discovered was that there seem to be two different kind of errors. One kind of error Visual Studio / Web Essential are handled with a wavy underline or telling the reason on the result window on the right, which is totally fine, but I am having trouble with "other kinds of errors", where my CSS simply doesn't get updated and it is not telling me why.

In the Output Window I can see:

```
SCSS: myfile.scss compilation failed: The service failed to respond to this request

        Possible cause: Syntax Error!
```

But no further details. Is there any kind of log file?

**OPEN: @mixing for image-width not working**

Calling the method image-width or image-height (as described here: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/ )
always ends up in an "Syntax Error!" error as shown in the open issue above.

The code I'm using is pretty simple (file in the same location and exists):

```
width: image-width("MyImage.jpg");
```

**SOLVED: Import Issue**

I could solve the problem why the following statement wasn't working:

```
@import "compass";
```

Instead, I have to specify a specific file and not a folder, like so:

```
@import "compass/reset/_utilities.scss";
```

Reason: Regarding to the sass-lang documentation, the decleration is not for folders, it is actually for "Partials" (http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4) and underscore sass files are treated as such. In my project I had the compass folder included, but I was missing the _compass.scss file (this is what @import "compass" was looking for).

**SOLVED: Calling basic Compass funtionallity**

I could solve: Basic Sass-functionality works, but by calling the compass mixin such as global-reset in, the renderd code looks like this

```
 ...
 elements-of-type(html5-block) { display: block; }
 ...
```

Solution: In the Visual Studio Options, Navigate to WebEssentials > SASS > Use Ruby Runtime and set the value to "True"

Comment: Does any of this apply to the new `Web Compiler`?